# How to use a true/false condition to pause video in an if loop of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I get an onclick even to return either true or false and store it in a variable.

```
 $('.box1').on('click', function(){
            boxClicked = true;
            video1[0].play();
        });
```

Later on in the code, I am using;

```
$(video1).on('timeupdate', function()
 {
       var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime);
       var durationNum = Math.round(this.duration);
       var formattedCurrentTime = secondsToHms(currentTime);
       var formattedDurationTime = secondsToHms(durationNum)
       onTrackedVideoFram(formattedCurrentTime, formattedDurationTime)

       if(currentTime == boxTime && boxClicked == true) { 
            video1[0].pause();
       }    
   });

});
```

`boxTime` is a variable with a prestored value of say, 10 
So it *should* at 10 sec duration check, if the `boxClick` is `true` or `false` and if `false`, it should *pause* the video.

My only problem... it is not doing that.

Comment: Two possibilities:  1) Did you declare `boxClicked` on global scope, so it will be available to both functions? 2) Are you certain `timeupdate` runs frequently enough that `currentTime` will at some point definitely be *exactly* 10?  (I'm suspecting the video frame rate may mean that the current time skips from a bit below 10 to a bit above 10, so never matches the exact condition.)

Comment: You are bingo on the time issue .. its never exact. On chrome its sometimes okay but on firefox it never stops at a particular point. 

Coding this out is not a solution for me because I am not sure about how to fix this. 

BUT I could create the video in a way so that slight difference in the frame stop wouldnt be noticeable.

Comment: And you're right it could be a global issue. 
I changed it from true to false liek @ajc2000 suggested and it worked (even though it shouldnt)

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to pause the video only when `boxClicked` is `false`.  If that is the case, then simply check for `boxClicked` to be `false` rather than `true` in your if-statement:

```
if(currentTime == boxTime && boxClicked == false) {
    video1[0].pause();
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that.
On click I changed boxclick to true, 
Used that true to trigger something else.